# Querying database for entries submitted within the past week using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm wanting to display the data I'm having stored in my database using codeigniter. Currently, the data is stored as a **datetime** type. I will also need to be able to query for the past month and year, so I'm wondering if there is some functions I haven't found yet that aid in this retrieval.

Here is the codeigniter query I'm using to grab the week's data. What's wrong here?

```
$this->db   
    ->select_sum('column1')
    ->select_sum('column2')
    ->where(YEARWEEK('created_at') == YEARWEEK(NOW()));
```

Currently, **created_at** is where the **datetime** type date is being stored.

Comment: What's the error? Not familiar enough with CI, but I imagine you need to quote the `where()` parameter.

Comment: There is no error, it's just showing a blank page once it's ran.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter, but I imagine it's something to the effect of `WHERE('created_at' >= NOW() - 7 DAYS)`

Comment: / I'm assuming the where() is where the problem is.

Comment: @GigaWatt I gave that a shot, but no luck.

Comment: What about: `->where("YEARWEEK('created_at')", "YEARWEEK(NOW())");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This always happens, doesn't it?)

So, I slept on it. Came into the office, and got it to work just fine.

Here's how my "where previous week" line now looks:

```
->where('created_at >=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week')));
```

Makes sense, I guess.